# Can you run Icinga Classic Web (icinga-html) and Icinga New Web (icinga-web) at the same time on top of the same Icinga instance?

Tags: debian-wheezy, icinga

I have an Icinga instance setup and running doing its usual job.  There is a plugin I wanted to try out (heatmap) that only seems to be supported under the newer Icinga-Web interface.  What I was hoping to do was run both the classing and newer web interfaces ontop of the same Icinga instance.

I have taken a look at the install instructions for [Icinga Classic](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart.html) and [Icinga Web](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/icinga-web-scratch.html); neither say what I am looking to do is impossible but neither say how to do it either.
(For background I am running on Debian Wheezy and would prefer to use the standard packages if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes, possible. There are different datasources as well as configurations involved, allowing to serve /icinga (Classic UI) and /icinga-web (new Web) by your preferred webserver.

Given the amount of questions, the docs team is working on a more detailed introduction on the 2 guis - find the latest and greatest here: http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/beginners.html#icinga_gui_comparison

Answer (score 0):

The Icinga folks confirmed that this is possible over on Twitter; as did one or two people I know who also use Icinga.

@[tafthorne](https://twitter.com/tafthorne) sure you can use icinga web and classic on the same instance:)

— Icinga (@icinga) [February 26, 2013](https://twitter.com/icinga/status/306363293331779584)

So I have run the apt-get icinga-web and things seem to be going OK.